# Validation not working on spring boot and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am new to spring boot and hibernate.I have declared a model class Office which is :

```
package com.ashwin.officeproject.model;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "office")
public class Office {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long officeId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "{officename.notempty}")
    private String officeName;

    @NotNull
    private int officeNumber;

    /*@Size(min = 8, max = 72, message = "Your offc address between 8 and 72 characters long")*/
    /*@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a offc name")*/
    private String officeAddress;

    public Office() {

    }

    //ommitted getters and setters
}
```

I have declared my first main starting class as:

```
package com.ashwin.officeproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OfficeProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OfficeProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
          = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

}
```

My controller class is:

```
package com.ashwin.officeproject.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.ashwin.officeproject.model.Office;
import com.ashwin.officeproject.repository.OfficeRepsitory;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    OfficeRepsitory officeRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/office"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String office(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("offices", new Office()); 
      return "office";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addOffice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("offices") Office office, 
      BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "error";
        }
        officeRepository.save(office);
        model.addAttribute("offices", new Office()); 
        return "office";
    }

}
```

I have a office.jsp page which is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<jsp:include page="./header.jsp" />
 <style>
      .error {
         color: #ff0000;
      }

      .errorblock {
         color: #000;
         background-color: #ffEEEE;
         border: 3px solid #ff0000;
         padding: 8px;
         margin: 16px;
      }
   </style>
    <form:form method="POST"  action="/addOffice"   modelAttribute="offices"  >

             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="officeName">Name</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="officeName"/></td>
                    <form:errors path = "officeName" cssClass = "error" />

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="officeNumber">Number</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="officeNumber"/></td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="officeAddress">
                      Address</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="officeAddress"/></td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>


<jsp:include page="./footer.jsp" />
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ashwin</groupId>
    <artifactId>OfficeProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OfficeProject</name>
    <description>OfficeProject</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I click the submit button then if the input field in my form are empty,I wanted to validate my form and show the message below the input field like **"Please provide valid office name"** .But what is happening is that when i hit the submit button then it is going to my error.jsp page but it is not showing any validation message which i have declared above.My error page displaying is:

error.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Error</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting any error in my console in eclipse too.It is just redirecting me in error.jsp page when my form's field is empty.

Comment: Can you try to add also `@NotNull` on `officeName` ?

Comment: i think @notnull is for Integer

Comment: That is exactly what you configured it to do. In case of error show `error.jsp`.

Comment: You should return `office` template for rendering model errors, since you have defined them there (`<form:errors path = "officeName" cssClass = "error" />`)

Comment: @Tijkijiki what should i need to change in my code?

Comment: `if (result.hasErrors()) { return "office"; }`

Comment: yes it worked but the message is not coming i have already added messages.properties inside src/main/resources and here {officename.notempty} is getting printed instead of message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

seems jar conflicts issue as `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar(javax.validation:validation-api:jar is part of hibernate validator)` is part of spring web dependency so no need to add extra dependency which might conflict so recommend to remove below dependencies and build project again by clean install(`mvn clean install`).

remove below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and make sure you access error message below: not required braces and property name match with your actual message property name you defined.(camelcase matters with name).

```
@NotEmpty(message = "officename.notempty")
```

Comment: i need to delete both or require one of them?

Comment: Need to delete both as they are part of web dependency

Comment: do i need to signup ? i managed to bring the error message but it is coming in {officename.notempty} like this

Comment: is there any issue you seeing in directly joining??

Comment: its is teeling me to sing in . Should i need to create a account or what? dont u have team viewer?

Comment: you can enter any personal email there to join if required as dont use teamviewer..

Comment: i'm facing same issue, but i'm still error even i followed your instruction, please check it out https://github.com/black-lotus/ppm-tool-be on `ValidDateValidator`

Comment: Starting from version `2.3.0.RELEASE` Spring Boot Web and WebFlux starters no longer depend on the validation starter, so you have to add `spring-boot-starter-validation` to your pom.xml. For details check 2.3.0 [Release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters)

Comment: Just a tip, you can check if HV is properly initialized in the first place by checking for the following log line at app startup (this is from a Spring Boot app, but other platforms should also probably display it): `[background-preinit]  INFO Version HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final`

Answer (score 1):

I migrated from Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE to 2.4.2 and as soon as I made the changes, the validation starts failing.

The reason to start failing is to remove the validation dependencies from web module from Spring Boot version 2.3.

I made below changes to run the validation.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${validation.api}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.classmate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Change the versions accordingly.